# GeoTools extract band

Tags: gdal, java, geotools, geotiff-tiff, band

I have a tiff image with 4 bands (Red, Green, Blue and Infrared) and I need to extract two of them.

I want to input one image and split it and make two images.
I want to do it with GeoTools since I use Java to develop.

How I do that?

*PS: I can do it with gdal and command line. (e.g. **gdal_translate -b 3 in.tiff out.tiff** which **3** is the number of band)*

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [`org.geotools.process.raster`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/class-use/GridCoverage2D.html)

> `BandSelectProcess.execute(GridCoverage2D coverage, int[] sampleDims, Integer visibleSampleDim)`
>
> `List<ZoneGeometry>    RasterZonalStatistics2.execute(GridCoverage2D coverage,   int[] bands, List<SimpleFeature> zones, GridCoverage2D classifier, Range nodata,   Geometry mask, boolean useROIAccessor, Polygon roi, Statistics.StatsType[] stats, double[] minbounds, double[] maxbounds, int[] numbins, List<Range> rangeData, boolean localStats)`